# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de crear un método para agregar un producto en la clase de un inventario en Java, dentro de un vector?

Tags: java, poo

Tengo una clase llamada RegistroInv en java, la cuál está diseñada para contener los arreglos de la clase Productos que contiene los atributos respectivos, los cuáles deberán estar enlazados más adelante con un arreglo unidimensional y una matriz de 5 columnas y 10 filas. Intentando crear el método respectivo para agregar un producto, con el objetivo de guardarlo en el vector, el compilador me rechaza el código. Tengo:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RegistroInv{

    public Productos producto[];
    public int tablaProductos[][];
    
    //Constructor de la clase
    public RegistroInv(){
        producto = new Productos [5];
        tablaProductos = new int [10][5];
        }
        
    //Codigo para agregrar productos
    public boolean addProducto (Productos productos){
        int i=0;
        boolean realizado=false;
        
            for ( i=0; i<producto.length; i++){
            
            if(producto[i]=0){
                
                producto [i] = productos ;
                realizado=true;
            }
            
            else{
                realizado=false;
            }
            
            }//Cierra ciclo
    
        return realizado;
    
    }//Cierra metodo agregar














}//Cierra la clase
```

No comprendo lo que me dice el compilador. Adjunto el codigo del objeto original Productos.java:

```
public class Productos{

    private String id;
    private String costo;
    private String marca;
    
    //Constructor 1
    public Productos (String id, String costo, String marca){
        
        setid (id);
        setCosto (costo);
        setMarca (marca);
    }

    //Metodos para la clase principal
    public void setid (String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getid(){
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setCosto (String costo){
        this.costo = costo;
    }
    
    public String getCosto (){
        return costo;
    }
    
    public void setMarca (String marca){
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    
    public String getMarca (){
        return marca;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return "Id de producto: "+getid()+"\nPrecio del producto: "+getCosto()+"\nMarca registrada: "+getMarca();
    }               
}
```

Error: RegistroInv.java:18: error: array required, but Productos found[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cual es el error del compilador?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El compilador te rechaza el codigo.. entonces sale un error.. que error?

Comment: Es: javac "RegistroInv.java" (en el directorio: D:\Carrera de Informática\II Semestre\Programación I\Evaluaciones\Examen)
RegistroInv.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  for ( i=0; i<producto.length; i++){
                       ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable producto of type Productos
RegistroInv.java:18: error: array required, but Productos found
   if (producto[i]=0){
               ^
RegistroInv.java:19: error: array required, but Productos found
    producto [i] = producto ;
             ^
3 errors
Ha fallado la compilación.

Comment: Array required, but int found

Comment: por favor, usa el boton [edit] y agrega el error en la pregunta...

Comment: de paso, seguro esto: if(productoAgregar[i]=null) esta mal

Comment: estas igualando al reves??? productoAgregar [i] = producto ;????

Comment: productoAgregar es un objeto.. no un array....

Comment: Hice varios cambios:  public boolean addProducto (Productos productos){
  int i=0;
  
  for ( i=0; i<producto.length; i++){
   
   if (producto[i]=0){
    producto [i] = productos ;

   }
   
   
   
  }//Cierra ciclo
 
 
 
 }//Cierra metodo agregar  Pero ahora me indica RegistroInv.java:18: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Productos , pero el error ahora solo esta en if (producto[i]=0){

Comment: Los errores y el codigo como texto, siempre... y todos los cambios en la pregunta.. y cual es la pregunta ahora?

Comment: eso te lo dije antes... vos queres asignar o comprobar si son iguales? cual es el operador de comprobacion y cual el de asignacion?

Comment: Bueno, mi pregunta es cómo hacer para solucionar que Java no me permite compilar la línea de código --  if(producto[i]=0){
    
    producto [i] = productos ;
    realizado=true;
   } --  Porque me indica -- int cannot be converted con Productos --

Comment: producto[i]=0, uno es un producto y otro es un entero, así que son incompatibles, eso es lo que dice tu error de compilador

Answer (score 1):

```
if(producto [i] = 0) {
    producto [i] = productos;
    realizado=true;
}
```

Hay un par de cosas mal en este bloque:

- Dentro del `if` se espera algo tipo booleano, y estas haciendo una asignación (=). Sustituye el `=` por `==` para comparar producto [i] con 0.
- De todas formas producto [i] es de tipo Productos y lo estas comparando con un `integer`.

Si lo que quieres comparar un campo concreto de producto [i] con 0, deberás implementar el `comparator` pertinente, o acceder al campo que quieres comparar mediante los `getters` que tienes implementados ( ten en cuenta que los campos de Productos son `Strings`). Quedaría algo así:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(producto [i].getid()) == 0) {
    producto [i] = productos;
    realizado = true;
}
```

Son los pequeños errores de sintaxis que veo, aunque no acabo de entender muy bien la funcionalidad...

Saludos!